# I cannot install webpack-cli

Tags: webpack

I'm trying the following:

```
npm i --save-dev webpack-cli
```

But, got the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Goran\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-03T06_07_52_
323Z-debug.log
```

How to install webpack-cli?

Comment: do you have git installed?

Comment: No. I don't have Git installed.

Comment: I've just installed Git and got the same error.

Comment: check if you can access git through command line else restart the command line..It probably did not get the updated environment path

Comment: It works after restarting cmd. Please, put your answer as regular one and I'll mark it as right one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory.

You need to install git in your system.
Also ensure it is set in your environment path.

You might need to restart your command prompt/terminal so that `git` program is found.

Comment: Why the heck does webpack-cli require git to be installed??? No other npm packages I'm using do, including webpack itself! This seems super dumb to me :(